# How to replace double quotes with space in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data file that has some records with ""(double quotes). I need to replace these quotes with space in scala using regexp_replace function.

Example : `regexp_replace(column_name, '\"' ," ")` but when i am trying to do that i am getting some error "unclosed" string literal.

Comment: regexp_replace(column_name, '\"', " ")

Comment: you can also use `translate` function

Comment: @AlexOtt thanks for the reply. Translate and regexp_replace function return unit type but i want to return string type in scala.

Comment: they are returning the `Column` type - this is how it works in Spark SQL. If you just need to replace everything in `String`, then you need to use `.replaceAll`

Comment: @AlexOtt but i need to use regexp_replace to replace double quotes(\") with space(" ").

Comment: val rep = "regexp.replace(column_name,'\"','')" ;
val colString = insertColumns.mkString(",") + s"${variable},concat(year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((${rep}), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),'-',lpad(month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((${rep}), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),2,'0'),'-',lpad(day(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((${rep}), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),2,'0')) AS column_name"

Comment: for this code, you need to use `column_name.replaceAll` because you're operating not on the column data as its' required for `regexp_replace`, but on the name of the column instead that is `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From using `regexp_replace` and mentioning columns I assume you mean Spark (if so, you should mention it in any future questions). Look at [the signature of the two overloads](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#regexp_replace(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,replacement:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

```
def regexp_replace(e: Column, pattern: Column, replacement: Column): Column
def regexp_replace(e: Column, pattern: String, replacement: String): Column
```

`'\"'` is a `Char`, not a `String`, so you need `"\""` instead.

In Scala without Spark you'd use methods like `replace{All,FirstSome}In` on [`scala.util.matching.Regex`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) (mentioned mostly for anyone else who finds this question).

Update:

> ```
> val colString = insertColumns.mkString(",") + s"${month},concat(year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp replace(column_name,'\"',"")), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),'-',lpad(month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp_replace(column_name,'\"',"")), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),2,'0'),'-',lpad(day(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp_replace(column_name,'\"',"")), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),2,'0')) AS column_name"
> ```

Here the string after `+` is only

```
s"${month},concat(year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp replace(column_name,'\"',"
```

and then you have separate string literals

```
")), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),'-',lpad(month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp_replace(column_name,'\"',"
```

etc.

`\"` inside an `s"..."` [doesn't work as expected](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6476), so escaping the quotes with `\"` won't work; you should use triple-quoted strings.

Comment: @alexy thanks for your reply. I have scala and i am using scala variable . I have posted full string . this is what I am trying to do but getting error "unclosed string literal".

Comment: val colString = insertColumns.mkString(",") + s"${month},concat(year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp replace(column_name,'\"',"")), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),'-',lpad(month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp_replace(column_name,'\"',"")), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),2,'0'),'-',lpad(day(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp_replace(column_name,'\"',"")), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),2,'0')) AS column_name"

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried below command
insertColumns.mkString(",") + s"""${column},concat(year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp_replace(column_name,\","")),

Comment: 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),'-',lpad(month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp_replace(column_name,\","")),

Comment: 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),2,'0'),'-',lpad(day(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp((regexp_replace(column_name,\","")),

Comment: 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))),2,'0')) AS column_name"""

Comment: Result i am getting : (regexp_replace(base_ts,",""))